# Fast interprocess event in .net core

Tags: .net, linux, macos, .net-core, memory-mapped-files

I am using a **Memory Mapped File** between many processes as a shared multi-writer and multi-reader queue. On Windows, I use a named `EventWaitHandle` to send a signal that there might be new messages in the queue so the subscribers should wake up and check the queue for possible messages.

However, on Linux and macOS, named `EventWaitHandles` are not supported. What are my options?

So far, I have tried:

1. Named `Semaphore` -- not supported on Linux and macOS
2. `FileSystemWatcher` -- it works, but it is relatively slow. (about `10ms` on my Macbook to receive a file change notification).
3. Named `Mutex` -- although named mutexes are supported on all platforms, I can't figure out a usage pattern that allows me to replicate the behavior of an `AutoResetEvent`. Is there one?
4. Poll (check for messages + thread sleep in a loop) - this works, but if the sleep is anything longer than 2ms, I will not meet my perf goal.
5. `Futex` -- seems very low-level for what I need. Would it work on both Linux and MacOS?and can I somehow `p/invoke` from a `.net core` app?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at unix sockets ? A blocking unix socket will respond to an event pretty much immediately. You'd need to define messages, and possibly implement callbacks to service the event and optionally respond.

Comment: @secretsquirrel, thanks for the suggestion. Domain sockets work but they also make the apps pretty complex. There are multiple writers and readers so figuring out who to connect the socket to is pretty hard. Do you know if I can use "conditional variables" from .net core?

Comment: I don't know about conditional variables; the mono documentation could help with that; just to achieve your purpose on Linux, there is the inotify system api, which can let a process know when a file has been changed: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html